# Worst-case running time Big O

Tags: java, big-o, complexity-theory

Could you please explain how I can get the worst-case Big O of this algorithm. I was reading my textbook and I came across a similar algorithm like this one but still don't understand the logic behind it.

```
int t=0;
for(int x=0;x<num.length;x++){
    for(int y=0;y<num.length;y++){
        for(int p=0;p<num.length;p++){
            for(int w=0;w<num.length;w++){
                if(num[p][w]>num[x][y])
                {
                    t=num[x][y];
                    num[x][y]=num[p][w];
                    num[p][w]=t;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logic is pretty simple. Let's start with the most inner loop:

This loop runs `num.length` times. Its worst case runtime complexity in big-O notation is `O(n)` assuming `n = num.length`.

```
for(int w=0;w<num.length;w++){
    ...
}
```

Now when you put another for-loop around it of length `p`, it will run the above for-loop `p` times. So it is `O(pn)`. In your case, `p = num.length = n` so it should be `O(n*n) = O(n^2)`.

There are 4 nested loops in your example so the answer is `O(n^4)`.

Why did I ignore the content of the most inner loop? Because there are a constant number of operations done, let that number be `c`. Asymptotic analysis used by the big-O notation says the following: `O(c) is equivalent to O(1)`. That comes from the [definition of big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: What about if I have a program and not just a particular algorithm that does "something" in specific". Let's say I have a program that operates(executes) different tasks;for example, let's say I have a program that generates random numbers within a matrix (2d array)  and then it sorts them in ascending order. The user is asked to enter any number that will make the program to print out a message specifying of whether the number chosen is in the array or not. Do I have to evaluate each statement individually?

Comment: How having different algorithms with its respective Big O notations get to the conclusion of the worst-case running time (Big O) when each algorithm is different.  Like when a program has algorithms: O(n^2), O(1), O(n).... Which one is the one that represents the entire program?

Comment: @Plrr When you have multiple Big O. Then that represent: The best-case scenario, average-case scenario and worst-case scenario. In programming we aim for the Average-case scenario. However, depending on the data input that you have. You might get the best-scenario or even the worst-case scenario. In all the one that "Happen most" is the average-case. You deal with this a lot.

Comment: @Plrr Do you mean that a program consists of multiple independent algorithms with differing worst case complexities? If that's the case, then the worst one is the one you pick. E.g. for `O(n^2), O(1), O(n)`, the overall worst case is `O(n^2)` because in the worst case, there is a quadratic growth.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing an element for; == or < or > against a list or an array of size n, Then its worst case is O(n).

Therefore the cost of one for loop is: O(n), but you have 4 for loops each with a worst case O(n).

Total cost is: n*n*n*n = Worst Case O(n^4).